# Joining with conditions

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

```
**payments**
ID  Sum
1   400
2   450
3   500

**orders**
ID  Payment
1   1       
2   3
3   2

**orders_info**
ID  ItemID  Qty Sum
1   1       1   400
2   12      2   225
3   8       1   500
```

Where:

```
payments.ID = orders.Payment
orders.ID = orders_info.ID
```

Now, if I join this up like below I'm gonna get wrong result:

```
select o.ID, sum(qty*sum)
from payments p
  inner join orders o on(p.ID = orders.Payment)
  inner join orders_info oi on(o.ID = oi.ID)
where oi.Qty < 2
group by o.ID
```

If I join like this, I'm gonna get way too many rows and therefor the sum() function will return a too high value. I need the info from orders_info without having to multiply its rows with the other tables. How can I achieve this?

So, basicly I want to have all payments made along with their value gotten from the order_info except if the qty is for example lesser than 2.

Comment: The `sum` in your `sum(qty*sum)`, is that `p.sum` or `oi.sum`?

Comment: in your sql you're saying "only show if Qty less than 2", and then in text you say "all payment [...] except if the qty is lesser than 2". A bit conflicting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply move your `oi.Qty > 2` to your join's on-clause to filter that specific table.

Example:

```
select o.ID,
       sum(oi.qty * oi.sum) -- Define if it should be p.sum or oi.sum!
  from payments     p
         inner join
       orders       o   on p.ID   = o.Payment
         inner join
       orders_info  oi  on o.ID   = oi.ID
                       and oi.Qty >= 2  -- This filters the specific table
group by o.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange that you dont get any error for having two columns name, "sum" is in both payments and in "order_info"...

```
select o.ID, sum(p.sum) 
from payments p 
inner join orders o 
on(p.ID = orders.Payment) 
inner join orders_info oi 
on(o.ID = oi.ID) 
where oi.Qty < 2 
group by o.ID
```

or

```
select o.ID, sum(io.sum*qty) 
from payments p 
inner join orders o 
on(p.ID = orders.Payment) 
inner join orders_info oi 
on(o.ID = oi.ID) 
where oi.Qty < 2 
group by o.ID
```

any of this should work

if you have the following it will be too high:

```
select o.ID, sum(p.sum*qty) 
from payments p 
inner join orders o 
on(p.ID = orders.Payment) 
inner join orders_info oi 
on(o.ID = oi.ID) 
where oi.Qty < 2 
group by o.ID
```

Comment: well, yeah. I wrote those examples on the fly sorry.